# how to init rwlock_t

Tags: linux-kernel, rwlock

I am writing a linux kernel module,
and I can't find a way to initialise my read-write lock.
I prefer a static init.

When I try using RW_LOCK_UNLOCKED, the compiler tells me that it is not defined.

```
rwlock_t lock = RW_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [the Source](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/rwlock_types.h), Luke:

```
DEFINE_RWLOCK(lock);
```